# Find function and copy data

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to use find function to find the row of the data and I want to copy the all chunk of data down the row from column A to H to another worksheet. However, the find function is not working. May I know if i did it correctly and I am very uncertain on how to copy the data down the row. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Dim r, ran, ranOff As Range
Set ran = Cells.Find(What:="#           pin/pkgpin  Schem Label  Pkg Pad  
Bank   Pkg Label  Pad/Bump Coord  Probe Coord  Pkg Coord")
Set ranOff = ran.Offset(1, 0)
ranOff.CurrentRegion.Select
```

Comment: What is the string you want to find ? is it the entire `":="#           pin/pkgpin  Schem Label  Pkg Pad  
Bank   Pkg Label  Pad/Bump Coord  Probe Coord  Pkg Coord"` ?

Comment: yes, it is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Importar_Dados()

Dim Ran As Range, RanOff As Range
Dim StrtoFind As String

' modify the string to Find here
StrtoFind = "#           pin/pkgpin  Schem Label  Pkg Pad Bank   Pkg Label  Pad/Bump Coord  Probe Coord  Pkg Coord"

Set Ran = Cells.Find(What:=StrtoFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not Ran Is Nothing Then ' <-- Find was able to find a match
     Set RanOff = Range("A" & Ran.Row + 1 & ":H" & Ran.Row + 1) '<-- set the range 1 row below, from column A to column H
     RanOff.Copy '<-- copy the range    
     ' rest of your code ...

Else ' unseuccessful Find
    MsgBox "unable to find " & StrtoFind
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it works now but now I have another qn: after i find the row, how do I copy data there is down the row ?

Comment: @RachelChia to copy the data one row below from column "A" to column "H" ?

Comment: hi jus to learn vba on the line of:   **Set RanOff = Range("A" & Ran.Row + 1 & ":H" & Ran.Row + 1)** what does " +1" do ?

Comment: @RachelChia `Ran.Row` will give you the row number where the `Find` was found, since you want to copy the row below, I added the `+1`

Comment: Thanks for always helping :)